# Angular gantt customize data fields

Tags: angularjs

Does angular gantt plugin allow to change the column header labels? I tried to change the side table headers but couldn't. If it doesn't allow what other gantt chart can I use? At the side table, I need to show work station, id and type. In the gannt chart, I need to show the particular ids under the respective priority numbers. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can change or defined the column header labels at property Options.

```
$scope.options = {
    ...
    treeTableColumns: ['from', 'to', 'myColumn'],
    columnsHeaders: { 'model.name': 'Name', 'from': 'From', 'to': 'To', 'myColumn': 'My column name' },
    columnsClasses: { //css
        'myColumn': 'myclass'
    },

    //defined content here. ex: String, checkbox, radio, ...
    //ex: <input type="checkbox" id={{row.model.id}} ng-model="row.model.myColumn">
    columnsContents: { 
        'myColumn': '{{row.model.myColumn}}',
        ...
    },
};

$scope.myData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Finalize concept',
    myColumn: 'content',
    tasks: [{
        id: 'Finalize concept',
        name: 'Finalize concept',
        priority: 10,
        color: '#F1C232',
        from: new Date(2013, 9, 17, 8, 0, 0),
        to: new Date(2013, 9, 18, 18, 0, 0),
        progress: 100
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Development',
    myColumn: 'content',
    children: ['Sprint 1', 'Sprint 2', 'Sprint 3', 'Sprint 4'],
    content: '<i class="fa fa-file-code-o" ng-click="scope.handleRowIconClick(row.model)"></i> {{row.model.name}}'
} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.angular-gantt.com/configuration/attributes/
Here yo have the answer about all you can do.

You cant change the column header labels but you can select between all the formats that you have:

```
$scope.headersFormats = { 
  'year': 'YYYY', 
  'quarter': '[Q]Q YYYY', 
  month: 'MMMM YYYY', 
  week: 'w', 
  day: 'D', 
  hour: 'H', 
  minute:'HH:mm'
};
```